# Someone searching "0x6461726b33636f6465" - what kind of exploit is this?

Tags: sql-injection, mysql

Recently spotted someone searching:

> 1 and 1 2 union select 0x6461726b31636f6465--

And a bunch of variations.  What type of exploit is this and what does it attempt to do?  I don't believe I'm at any particular risk, but it would be helpful to understand what the goal of the attacker is here so I can be sure since I've never seen this before.

Also, it's worth noting that searching "0x6461726b31636f6465" on google yields a ton of results.  Why would google be crawling and indexing a search term that clearly appears to be a vulnerability exploit of some sort?

Comment: Seems like an SQL injection. Just converted `6461726b31636f6465` to ASCII, and it reads `dark1code`, not sure what exactly it means, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's an SQL injection and the "dark1code" is just a column value that the attacker intends to include into the result set. if the result of the SQL query is reflected in the response html page somewhere then the attacker can see that his injection is being reflected.